# Why isn't energy created by the superposition of waves?

Tags: waves, superposition

Two identical waves, of amplitude $A$, have energy proportional to $A^2$. The sum of the energies of these two waves being proportional to $2A^2$.

If these two waves superimpose to form a wave of the same form with amplitude $2A$. The energy of this wave will now be proportional to $(2A)^2 = 4A^2$. This suggests an increase in energy by a factor of $2$, which is a contradiction to the conservation of energy.

How is this rectified please?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7707/energy-conservation-and-interference

Comment: Ronny, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/229739/46708) about dissipation and deflection phenomena.